# Is there a way to use logical statements in an html merge document?

Tags: html, xml, merge, logical-operators

My work uses HTML email templates that uses placeholders to insert information from a separate XML document.

I have been tasked with setting up a new template that will only contain information for the first 2 products and nothing else, but they want me to keep the remaining products in the XML file for 'future-proofing'. I have no idea how to set up the template to limit to the first 2 records. Is there a way to use logical statements in html and would that work?

I don't even know what this type of query is, otherwise I would search myself.

Here is the code for the HTML template:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="Line">
      <td>
        <table>
           <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <td><a href="https://www.acompany.uk"> <img src="www.aproduct.uk/[Element1].jpg?></a</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td><a href="https://www.acompany.uk">[Element2]</a></td>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
         </table> 
        </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

And here is an excerpt from the XML that it looks at

```
<Line>
       <Element1>Name 1</Element1>
       <Element2>Description 1</Element2>
       <UniqueID>1</UniqueID>
</Line>
<Line>
       <Element1>Name 2</Element1>
       <Element2>Description 2</Element2>
       <UniqueID>2</UniqueID>
</Line>
<Line>
       <Element1>Name 3</Element1>
       <Element2>Description 3</Element2>
       <UniqueID>3</UniqueID>
</Line>
```

When it runs, it will populate the image and description of all products in the document with the `<Line>` header. But, we only want to use the first 2 records.

*N.B I did not set these up myself, the person who did left in a hurry and it's landed in my lap.*

Comment: There are 2 ways to approach this.  First with code, you could crawl through your template, locate elements and attributes that contain '[Element]', and replace.

Comment: Alternatively, you could convert your template to XSL, and transform the <Line> XML file, replacing the [Element] tags with <xsl:value-of select/>.

Comment: Thanks for your help, in your first suggestion what would I need to replace the Element with if I were to just amend the template?